# Change image src as toggle button works

Tags: jquery

when i'm using this code ,when i click nav-btn one time it become changed but when i click second time content will hide and nav-btn (src) unchanged 
i want to get the default src(drop down-icon) when i click second time(but my button still close-icon)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.nav-btn").click(function(){
        $("nav>ul").toggle('slow');
    $(".nav-btn").attr('src', 'http://www.salmanulfaris.com/GEM/images/button_1.png')(500);
    });
 });
```

```css
.nav-ul {
 background-color:#252525;
 width:100%;
 display:none;
 padding: 40px 0px 10px 0px;
 margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
 position:absolute;
 height:375px;
 right:0;
}
.nav-ul > li {
 display:block;
 width:50%;
 border-bottom:solid 1.5px #57d846;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-bottom:25px;
 font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
                 <img src="http://www.salmanulfaris.com/GEM/images/button.png" class="nav-btn">
                  <ul class="nav-ul" id="">
                     <li><a href="#" >HOME</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#" >TUTORIALS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ARTICLES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                  </ul>                 
              </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you only set the `src` of the `img` once. Instead you need to check what the current `src` is then toggle it on each click, something like this:

```js
$("img.nav-btn").click(function() {
  $("nav > ul").toggle('slow');
  $(".nav-btn").attr('src', function(i, src) {
      return src == 'http://www.salmanulfaris.com/GEM/images/button.png' ? 'http://www.salmanulfaris.com/GEM/images/button_1.png' : 'http://www.salmanulfaris.com/GEM/images/button.png';
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-ul {
  background-color: #252525;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 40px 0px 10px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 375px;
  right: 0;
}

.nav-ul>li {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: solid 1.5px #57d846;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <img src="http://www.salmanulfaris.com/GEM/images/button.png" class="nav-btn">
  <ul class="nav-ul" id="">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TUTORIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ARTICLES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```